# Adding rows of JTextFields to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, layout-manager

I need some advice on which Swing Components to choose in order to achieve the following:

I have something like a "table" structure, that every time that I click the "Add" button, another "row" should be inserted on the "table". Each row is composed of 2 `JTextField`. The problem I am having with the GridLayout (the layout used in the pictures below) is that if I add another row, then the heights of the text fields will be shortened and I don't want that (picture on the right), I want to preserve the same height for every row.

What I would like to happen is to have the extra row appear below the last one, so that I could use the `JScrollPane` and scroll to see it.

[image]

Should I use another layout rather than the GridLayout? Maybe the AbsoluteLayout or even using the Table Component?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions: You really want JTextFields with that large height? Why not use a JTable? And then setting the row height property. Have you tried nesting layouts, often a good solution for simplifying complex Swing layout problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a JTable and set the row height to whatever you desire.  For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableEg {
   private static final int ROW_HEIGHT = 40;
   private static final String[] TABLE_COLUMNS = {"Foo", "Bar"};

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(TABLE_COLUMNS, 2);
      JTable table = new JTable(tableModel );
      table.setRowHeight(ROW_HEIGHT);
      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

      JButton addRowBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Row") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            tableModel.addRow(new String[]{"", ""});
         }
      });
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(addRowBtn);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that you add your JTextField in a Jpanel, and you Jpanel in a JScrollPane. Now you would set a preferredSize for you JScrollPane (since you want a fixed displayable area), but you modify the height of the JPanel dinamically based in the amount of JTextField you are placing at that time.

In other words, if you have 2 JTextField in a Jpanel set with GridLayout of 2 columns; you JTextField would take the entire height of the Jpanel; but if you include 2 more they would have to make room for this two and therefore shortening.

Notice that you have 2 rows in a JPanel set to "100" height each row would use "50". if you add another row but also modify the height of the JPanel to "150" each JTextField would still take "50" pixels.

I am a newbie, and it is a possibility that i am not 100% right; if that it is the case "Sorry". I just wanted help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(Your_Table);
```

This will make your table to scroll....